# Avro C++ convert avro object to json

Tags: c++, avro

I'm using the Avro C++ library. I have a binary object obtained using the "decode" function and a stream of bytes as source. I would need to convert it to a json string, the object schema is available. Is there a way to do this? I couldn't find an example.

Comment: Perhaps you missed the [`jsonEncoder` method](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/cpp/html/namespaceavro.html#a7ac8a9c93b0621227de3dcca383e36ff)?

Comment: Suggest you make a self-answer with your solution, so others can find it too.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this way:

```
ObjectType Object;

std::unique_ptr<avro::InputStream> ObjectInputStream = avro::memoryInputStream((uint8_t *)PointerToBinaryData, BinaryDataSize);

avro::DecoderPtr Decoder = avro::binaryDecoder();

Decoder->init(*ObjectInputStream);

avro::decode(*Decoder, Object);

std::ifstream SchemaFile("/path_to_the_schema/schema_file.avsc");

avro::ValidSchema Schema;

avro::compileJsonSchema(SchemaFile, Schema);

std::unique_ptr<avro::OutputStream> JsonOutputFile = avro::fileOutputStream("path_to_json_file/json_file.json");

avro::EncoderPtr JsonEncoder = avro::jsonPrettyEncoder(Schema);

JsonEncoder->init(*JsonOutputFile);

avro::encode(*JsonEncoder, Object);

JsonEncoder->flush();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).